# npm install grpc is failing on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: grpc

I'm trying to install grpc on ubuntu 16.04. But it is failing with below error.
I have installed libgrpc-dev and libgrpc0

```
vagrant@fabric:~/hyperledger/fabric-samples/fabcar$ npm install grpc

> grpc@1.11.3 install /home/vagrant/hyperledger/fabric-samples/fabcar/node_modules/grpc
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library

node-pre-gyp ERR! Completion callback never invoked!
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Linux 4.4.0-121-generic
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/home/vagrant/hyperledger/fabric-samples/fabcar/node_modules/grpc/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /home/vagrant/hyperledger/fabric-samples/fabcar/node_modules/grpc
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v8.9.1
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.10.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! This is a bug in `node-pre-gyp`.
node-pre-gyp ERR! Try to update node-pre-gyp and file an issue if it does not help:
node-pre-gyp ERR!     <https://github.com/mapbox/node-pre-gyp/issues>
npm WARN fabcar@1.0.0 No repository field.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 6
npm ERR! grpc@1.11.3 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library`
npm ERR! Exit status 6
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the grpc@1.11.3 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/vagrant/.npm/_logs/2018-05-10T09_58_11_489Z-debug.log
```

Comment: This is a known bug in node-pre-gyp: https://github.com/mapbox/node-pre-gyp/issues/367. Currently there is not a known solution.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that i was trying  to install it behind a corporate proxy. it worked perfectly in open network.

Refer below issues for more information:

https://github.com/grpc/grpc-node/issues/140

https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/695